# Angular - Add XSRF every http call

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

In a **Angular** project i try to add interceptor (called *XSRF TOKEN*) to every calls. Code is similar to

*Interceptor*

```
 import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { Observable } from "rxjs";
    
    @Injectable()
    export class HttpXsrfInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    
      constructor() {
      }
    
      intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       // if (!req.headers.has('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
          req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('XSRF-TOKEN', 'TEST') });
        //}
        return next.handle(req);
      }
    }
```

**Admin.ts**

```
  providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: HttpXsrfInterceptor, multi: true }],
```

The problem: This interceptor does not appear in headers

*Network*

[image]

So: This is the correct way to add an interceptor in angular? Something is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the request variable (`req = ...`), because you are cloning the original request, not altering it.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  if (!req.headers.has('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
    req = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('XSRF-TOKEN', 'TEST') });
  }

  return next.handle(req);
}
```